# Create a regex for firstname and lastname

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a regular expression which does not allow space at first place but it allow space only in between the words and special character/numbers are not allowed.
For example:John Wick
I am trying with below regex expression:
/^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_ ]*[a-zA-Z_]$/g

Comment: @Gimby oh yes, right, _there_ was a space character in there, I overlooked that. (But since it is in a character class, it would still allow an arbitrary number of spaces _anywhere_, so what OP had was not the right thing either way.)

Comment: There exist names with hyphens, apostrophes and spaces.  Some times the "First" name isn't first.  Are you being overly restrictive?  Or is this a exercise?

Answer (score 3):

this given regex will for

```
 let name = 'Ashish Mishra';
 let reg = /^[a-zA-Z]+\s[A-Za-z]*$/g
 alert(reg.test(name))
```

Answer (score 3):

This regex ensures there are two words (First name and Last Name), no more no less.  The string cannot begin with a space and must end with a letter.  First name and last name must both begin with uppercase letters followed by 0 or more lowercase letters (maybe a name is only one letter).  In case first name and last name must have more than one character just replace asterisks with plush sign.

`^[A-Z][a-z]*\s[A-Z][a-z]*$`

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$/g
```

[a-zA-Z] : Match a single character

+ : Matches between 1 an unilimited

\s : whitespace

Comment: `* : Matches between 0 an unilimited` – and that’s why you should rather use `+` here to begin with - otherwise, a single space character passes as a valid “firstname lastname” combination here, and that’s surely not the intended result.

Comment: Also, you removed the anchoring of the pattern at start and end, so any _arbitrary_ stuff before and after the name would also be allowed - also not what OP wants here, I assume.

Comment: yes, thanks, i edit the answer